# Strange error compiling with NASM compiler

Tags: assembly, nasm, intel-syntax

I'm officially stumped... I'm getting the strangest error compiling this `.ASM` file... For some reason, the line `mov bx, word [w1]` causes the compiler to say the following: `error: invalid effective address`. However, the line before it, `mov ax, word [w0]` compiles just fine. I thought maybe it was a problem with how I defined w1, so I looked back and found that I defined both w0 and w1 were exactly identical minus the label: `w0 dw 0` and `w1 dw 0`. I have absolutely no idea what's causing it! So, here's the source if you'd like to attempt compiling it yourselves...

```
BITS 16
ORG 32768

w0 dw 0
w1 dw 0
w2 dw 0
os_drawbg equ 002Ah

drawbg:
mov ax, word [w0]
mov bx, word [w1]
mov cx, word [w2]
call os_drawbg
ret
```

Anyways, my question is, what is causing this, and how would I fix this problem?

Edit: Full code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/NFqcDnhZ

Comment: Also, there is this strange anomaly happening where I get errors supposedly on lines that, when I checked the .ASM file, don't actually exist. It really is quite strange, especially for such a simple file.

Comment: Are you sure you are not compiling another file? I just checked the snippet and it compiles just fine with NASM.

Comment: @MargaretBloom I just double checked, I am compiling the correct file... It's quite strange. There is more code, but I posted only the relevant parts to the error. Would you like me to update the question with the full source? (about 60 lines)

Comment: Well, you should make a [mcve]. You can still try posting the whole code though.

Comment: @MargretBloom Here's the erroneous code, to see if you can take a crack at compiling this.. http://pastebin.com/NFqcDnhZ

Comment: Is `w1` beyond the end of the segment, so no 16-bit absolute address can address it with the current value of  `DS`?  I think NASM knows about 16-bit segmentation.  If that's not it, reduce your example down to something as small as possible but still demonstrating the problem.  (Check it yourself with NASM on your end).

Comment: `mov ax, byte [b0]` at line 45 is illegal because *AX* is 16 bits, so you either: 1) use `mov ax, WORD [b0]` if you want to move a WORD 2) use `movzx ax, BYTE [b0]` is you want to move *b0* in *AX* by zero extending it to 16 bits (i.e. *AH* will be zero) 3) use `movsx ax, BYTE [b0]` is you want to move *b0* in *AX* by sign extending it to 16 bits  (i.e. *AH* will be 1 if *b0* > 7fh, 0 otherwise).

Comment: On pastebin line 45: "mov ax, byte [b0]" -> "error: mismatch in operand sizes" (that's correct, that instruction is invalid). And I have 4 other warnings about uninitialized declarations outside of .bss. Otherwise it compiles fine into .com target (not sure what your true target is).

Comment: You also use `resb` which is misleading in a binary file. Consider using `TIMES`

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd be shocked, it's only 60 or so lines of basic code, and it's all within the same segment I'm almost certain. :/

Comment: Then you should bisect it down to a [mcve].  You should [edit] your question so it contains code that you can copy&paste into a file on your system and reproduce the problem.  Also include your NASM command line, in case that's relevant.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thank you! At first I thought it was caused by a possible bug in my own compiler (working on a programming language), and thought it improperly generated code, but the problem was in the original source file from my own language `ax = b0`(supposed to be `ax = w0`), so thanks for spotting that typo! I apologise for posting a question without reviewing my own code closely enough first. Also, the target is binary. All compiles perfectly now (